# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016, Business Unit ID Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to query Business Unit ID from equipment, but i am getting an error

```
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
qe.EntityName = "equipment";
qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
qe.ColumnSet.AddColumns("equipmentid", "name", "businessunitid");
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal,EquipmentDropdown.Text);
EntityCollection resultequipments = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
if(resultequipments.Entities.Count > 0)
{
   Equipmentid = (Guid)resultequipments.Entities[0]["equipmentid"];
   Buid = (Guid)resultequipments.Entities[0]["businessunitid"]; // error at this line
}
```

Some one please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Modify your last but one line like this: `Buid = ((EntityReference)resultequipments.Entities[0]["businessunitid"]).Id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug your code, you'll see that the businessunitid attribute is an EntityReference, not a Guid.  Do this:

```
var entityRef = (EntityReference)resultequipments.Entities[0]["businessunitid"];
var Buid = entityRef.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must make a loop to read the entityCollection

```
        ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
        condition.AttributeName = "name";
        condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.NotNull;
        condition.Values.Add(EquipmentDropdown.Text);

        ColumnSet columns = new ColumnSet("equipmentid", "name", "businessunitid");

        QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
        qe.EntityName = "equipment";
        qe.ColumnSet = columns;

        EntityCollection resultequipments = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
        foreach(Entity r in resultequipments.Entities)
        {
                Console.WriteLine( r.Attributes["equipmentid"]);
                Console.WriteLine(r.Attributes["businessunitid"]); // error at this line
        }
                }
            }
```

Comment: No its still throwing error saying "Invalid Cast exception" because in values section we have "Microsoft.SDK." kind of... so its an object cannot type cast.